# Trigger a GitHub action when adding or removing someone from a team

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm currently managing the access to a specific computer using the users from a team in GitHub. I periodically run the action that does the synchronization but this is is far from optimal. I would like to be able to trigger a GitHub action whenever I add or remove a member in a specific team. I have already checked https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows but no event there seems to do exactly this. Is there any workaround to solve this?

Comment: Is this team part of an organization?

Comment: It is part of an organization, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need an application that can receive and process webhooks.

[Create a webhook](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/creating-webhooks) for the [`membership` event](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#membership) in the organisation you want to monitor.

Create a GitHub Actions workflow with the trigger `repository_dispatch`.

On receiving the webhook in your application, [create a repository dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) via the GitHub REST API to trigger the workflow you created.